# Is there a cleaner way to do this in Java try-catch?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, catch-block

```
try
{
    try
    {
        function(a, b);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("---------------------------------");
}
```

I do this nested try-catch block for a reason, which is simply that when I try this

```
try
{
    function(a, b);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("---------------------------------");
}
```

The line I print comes in the middle of the stack-trace most the time..

My question is why does that happen most the time ? and is there a cleaner way to avoid that issue ?

Comment: what is the issue? :O. Your first part shows redundancy.

Comment: *The line I print comes in the middle of the stack-trace most the time.* which is the line I

Comment: This code runs on a Java Enterprise Environment using EJB framework, the second code prints the line inside the trace-stack most the time, like that `e.printStackTrace()` and `System.out..` are not executed sequentially

Comment: e.printStackTrace(); outputs to the standard error and the System.out.println to the standar output.  Try to change to System.err.println("------");

Comment: `closed as unclear` SO is full of jokes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the stack trace is written to the standard error stream, whereas your line is written to the standard output stream. Replace it by

```
e.printStackTrace();
System.err.println("---------------------------------");
```

or to

```
e.printStackTrace(System.out);
System.out.println("---------------------------------");
```

In an enterprise application even more than in a client application, you should not print to the standard streams anyway. Use a real logging framework like slf4j, which will allow you to choose levels of logging, destinations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As `Throwable.printStackTrace()` and `System.out.println(Object)` write to different consoles (`stderr` and `stdout`), they might not be synchronized.

1st proposal: write the error to the `stdout`:

```
e.printStackTrace(System.out);
```

or 2nd proposal: explicitly flush the `stderr` buffer (and use it like in your second variant):

```
e.printStackTrace();
System.err.flush();
System.out.println(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the "--------" comes inbetween the printed stack trace because the exception is printed on `System.err` while the "------" is printed on the `System.out`, but both print to the console.

So this can happen:

1. `e.printStackTrace()` prints everything to `System.err`, but not all is immediatly flushed to the console.
2. `System.out.println("--------------")` prints the "----" to `System.out` and immediatly flushes it.
3. the rest of the `System.err` is now flushed

Flush the error stream before using `System.out` if you want `System.err` and `System.out` to appear in sequence in the console.

```
e.printStackTrace();
System.err.flush();
System.out.println("---------------------------------");
```

or use the error stream for both

```
e.printStackTrace();
System.err.println("---------------------------------");
```